# How do you access country/state/province polygons in google maps api?

Tags: android, overlay, google-maps

I have fairly large map overlay that I am displaying over the google maps data but would still like to see the country/state/province lines through my overlay (so the lines would essentially be *on top* of my overlay).

As I understand, these lines are simply polygons drawn over the maps.  Is there any way to access these?  If so, how do I get them to show up through my overlay images?

Answer (score 0):

> would still like to see the
>   country/state/province lines through
>   my overlay

You can achieve this via appropriate transparency on the items in your overlay.

> (so the lines would essentially be on
>   top of my overlay)

I am not aware that this is possible in Android.

> Is there any way to access these?

Not that I am aware of.

If you are more comfortable working with the Web-based Maps API, you can always use that in a `WebView` widget, instead of using a `MapView`. There are a number of apps on the Market that work this way.